# Select and export rows that is equal to values from another file from Tab delimited text files

Tags: python, excel

I have a large Tab Delimited TXT file and an excel file. I need to extract the rows from TXT of which column A values equal to the column A values in the excel. If the TXT file is not too large, I can just use Advanced Filter function in excel to do. But right now the file is too big..

TXT example:

```
A B C D 
1 
2
3
```

Excel

```
A
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: text file is a file called 'values.txt'; it has a header row which will not be used, and Excel file is a file called 'source.xlsx', where the data is on a worksheet called 'Sheet1'.

To get the list of items you want to select:

```
import openpyxl, csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='source.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
# this is a list generator which scans column 'A' for a continuous list
source_values = [ row[0].value for row in ws.rows ]
```

To get the data to be filtered from the text file:

```
with open('values.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    value_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
# this command pushes past the first row and discards the headers
    next(value_reader, None)
# list comprehension which assumes values read for Excel's column A were all integers - if not, e.g. if mixed numbers and text, will need a more complex function to be used
    values_chosen = [ x for x in value_reader if int(x[0]) in source_values]
```

Go ahead and use values_chosen for whatever purpose you need. Note it will be a nested list i.e. `[['3', 'Him'], ['5', 'We'], ['6', 'You']]`